# Object Duration in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Iam facing :ORA-21780: Maximum number of object durations exceeded error after I modified package code and included nested table type in PLSQL Oracle 11g.How to find the cause of the issue

Analysed the code .I wanted to understand the error and ways to debug it.

Comment: This is usually due to infinite recursion or some other code branching flaw in a loop. Folks aren't going to be able to provide much help though unless you show some code that presents a minimally reproducible example of the error.